# The Android Studio emulator doesnt sound. Ubuntu 19.10 distribution

Tags: command-line, drivers, sound, pulseaudio, 19.10

I have an MSI P65 with Ubuntu 19.10 distro. My emulator in Adroid Studio is not working properly. It doesnt sound. The event log of Android Studio show these warnings/erros:

- 18:41    Emulator: Fontconfig error:
  "/home/fabrizio/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf", line 10: junk after
  document element
- 18:41    Emulator: pulseaudio: pa_context_connect() failed
- 18:41    Emulator: pulseaudio: Reason: Connection refused
- 18:41  Emulator: pulseaudio: Failed to initialize PA contextaudio:
  Could not init `pa' audio driver

And if i use the command 'pulseaudio' in terminal i get these errors:

- E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
- E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.

Already tried to delete the files into .config/pulse but it didnt work. As u can wonder: work with an emulator in this condition is insane.

**Please Help.**